# ¿Como un router wifi envía notificación en android para registrarse?

Tags: android, router

Generalmente los router públicos solicitan registrarse para poder utilizar el Internet en el que aparece en una barra de notificación en el celular.
¿Como obtiene acceso en la barra de notificaciones?.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te refieres a cuando el dispositivo android detecta que hay una señal de wifi nueva detectada?

Comment: @DarckBlezzer No cuando uno se conecta a la red wifi, te envía una notificación para registrarse o inicia sesión, agregue una foto de referencia a la pregunta.

Comment: normalmente he configurado dispositivos wifi, router, pero nunca he visto alguna configuracion como esa, tal vez esa notificacion sea de la aplicacin de android por defaul, y te salga la notificacion cuando es una red de ese tipo...

Comment: si, estoy averiguando de que manera puedo replicarla,ya que aparecen en los  aeropuertos, tiendas, etc...  y no entiendo de que manera se logra

Comment: El router no envía ninguna notificación. La notificación es nativa de Android, y se dispara luego de acceder a una red que se encuentra detrás de un proxy que necesita autentificarse.

Comment: También puede que utilice un **Portal Cautivo**, en los aeropuertos es muy común encontrarlos. [Ejemplo de Portal Cautivo](http://recursostic.educacion.es/observatorio/web/gl/equipamiento-tecnologico/redes/1005-como-crear-tu-portal-cautivo-con-easy-hotspot)

Comment: @JoseLuisMontañes "Portal cautivo" es una forma de llamarlo. Pero es un proxy que hace que no tenga acceso a internet. Cuando Android detecta esto, saca la notificación.

Comment: @Mariano muchas gracias, ahora comprendo el funcionamiento de android sobre la barra de notificaciones , saludos!!